# How to get dlib eye rectangle of both eyes?

Tags: opencv, dlib

I try to get eyes regions from dlib:

```
eye_rect = centered_rect(dlib::point(shape.part(42)(0),shape.part(40)(0)),50 , 50);
```

But I didn't succeed.

How can I get both eyes region as rectangle?